# NGINX memory leak by importing videojs and videojs-record

Tags: nginx, memory-leaks, video.js, videojs-record

I'm getting these errors when I'm running `npm run build` by just importing videojs and videojs-record.
Yes, I removed my codes and leave just the imports.

[image]

I've increased memory to 8gb with:

`export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"`

but the error persisted.

I tried rebooting my EC2 instance with no progress.

I'm following this.

[image]

Btw, when I build on local machine, it's building just right. Error occurs only on nginx.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I updated t2.micro to t2.medium in my EC2 instance. Never thought of it. How stupid. haha